# User access log to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, logging, statistics

I need to get a log of user access to our `SQL Server` so I can track **average** and **peak concurrency usage**. Is there a hidden table or something I'm missing that has this information for me? To my knowledge the application I'm looking at does not track this at the application level.

I'm currently working on `SQL Server 2000`, but will moving to `SQL Server 2005` shortly, so solutions for both are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005, go to tree view on the left and select Server (name of the actual server) > Management > Activity Monitor.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

- on `2000` you can use `sp_who2` or the `dbo.sysprocesses` system table
- on `2005` take a look at the `sys.dm_exec_sessions` DMV

Below is an example

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS StatusCount,CASE status 
WHEN 'Running' THEN 'Running - Currently running one or more requests' 
WHEN 'Sleeping ' THEN 'Sleeping - Currently running no requests' 
ELSE 'Dormant – Session is in prelogin state' END status 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
GROUP BY status
```